# jStatic simple HTTP server with ability to reload pages when files are changed

Tags: web-development, html, node.js, http

I'm looking for an HTTP server that can be invoked from the command line for `localhost`. I want it to be able to watch static html and css files for changes and reload the page viewed in a browser when changes are noticed.

I've found a number of `nodejs` packages filling this task, but many of them don't work well. Here are the `nodejs` packages I tried:

- [`live-server`](https://npmjs.com/package/live-server) is doing it good for the default `default.html` and `index.html` pages. If I want to watch an HTML page which is not `index.html` or `default.html`, I don't see the browser actually updates.
- [`fast-live-reload`](https://npmjs.com/package/fast-live-reload) perhaps is not suited for static web pages and only for web applications of some sort.
- [`livereload`](https://npmjs.com/package/livereload) just doesn't work at all, perhaps it is not suited for static web pages and only for web applications as well

### EDIT

- `nginx` is an overkill.

[`webpack-dev-server`](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html#webpack-dev-server-cli) seems like is good choice only for people who work with the webpack JS framework. I tried it with `webpack-dev-server .` and it gives me the following errors:

```
ERROR in multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/home/doron/repos/mathrills.com/' in '/home/doron/repos/mathrills.com'
@ multi (webpack)-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080 ./
webpack: Failed to compile
```

While searching the internet, it seemed that most of these packages are not meant for static and plain HTML and CSS web pages. I'm not a web applications developer. I just want to write plain HTML and CSS and that's all.

Comment: Well, the only way to do this with HTML pages only and no specific server support is to have the page regularly reload itself on a timer and configure the page so it is not cached by the browser (probably with `<meta>` tags).  Any sort of smart reload that only reloads when the page actually changes on the server will need custom server support for that and will likely need a persistent webSocket connection from web page to server to the browser can be told by the server when to fetch updated content.

Answer (score 1):

There was a question about this on StackOverflow several years ago:

[Best lightweight web server (only static content) for windows](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5119307/1593077)

Options suggested there were:

1. [**Mongoose**](https://github.com/cesanta/mongoose): A small, single executable, embeddable server <- but you'd need to check if it can notice changes to the static files
2. Use the Python webserver module (i.e. `python -m http.server <PORT>`) - assuming you can configure it to do what you want
3. [**thttpd**](http://www.acme.com/software/thttpd/thttpd_man.html) : A nother very small server; it's man page says it monitors the configuration file for changes, so chances are it also monitors the served files for changes (or simply doesn't cache a copy of them).
4. [**nginx**](http://nginx.org/en/) or [**lighttpd**](http://www.lighttpd.net/): Possibly overkill in terms of features, but nginx is modular and both have small footprints, supposedly.

and there are more...

Answer (score 1):

You're talking about something to reload the web browser while you write HTML/CSS right?

[webpack-dev-server](https://webpack.github.io/docs/webpack-dev-server.html) is perfect for this.

You should be able to find a yeoman generator to set up the right boiler plate for you. But if you're interested, you can just [clone a project I have for writing my CV in HTML](https://github.com/dwjohnston/cv), which does what you're looking for.

Comment: First of all, *yes*, I want it only for pure HTML,CSS and JS. Additionally, I tried `webpack-dev-server` and I get lot's of errors about unfound modules. I edited the original post.

Comment: ... Did you run `npm install`? Getting started with npm/node can be a bit of work at first - as there are a few dependencies that you need to use first. Did you try my github project?

Comment: Of course I did, I installed `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server` with `npm install -g`.